# Coordinates of the centroid in a 3D rectangle

Tags: 3d, rectangles, centroid

I have a 3D rectangle and I have to find the 3D coordinates of its centroid. I tried to take 4 vertices, one let's say the origin $o$ and the three adjacent vertices $a, b, c$.

I computed the distances between the pairs "origin-vertex" using this $\sqrt{(o_x - a_x)^2+(o_y - a_y)^2+(o_z - a_z)^2}$ to compute the length, this $\sqrt{(o_x - b_x)^2+(o_y - b_y)^2+(o_z - b_z)^2}$ to compute the width and this $\sqrt{(o_x - c_x)^2+(o_y - c_y)^2+(o_z - c_z)^2}$ to compute the height.

(I'm doing this because my coordinates are not coplanar, otherwise, I could consider just the $x$ coordinate for the length, ...)

Then I added the coordinates of the origin, respectively $o_x$ to the $\frac{length}{2}$, $o_y$ to the $\frac{width}{2}$ and $o_z$ to the $\frac{height}{2}$.

But what I'm getting is this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7qo3.png)

So what's the problem with my solution?

Comment: If the points aren’t coplanar, then you don’t have a rectangle.

Comment: What I mean is that for example, the origin is $(37.5, 0.2, -0.3)$ and $a$ is $(39.4, 0.1, -0.1)$

Comment: If it really is a rectangle, you can just add up all of the vertex coordinates and divide by four or find the intersection of the diagonals, as one might in two dimensions.

Comment: You say you have a rectangle, but your picture shows a box (a.k.a. a cuboid). Are you trying to find the centroid of one of the rectangular faces of the box, or the centroid of the whole box?

Comment: User, you probably mean "not axis-aligned", when you wrote "not coplanar".

Comment: @NominalAnimal probably.. I'm not a mathematician so I don't know the exact term, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you know one vertex of the cuboid, $\vec{o}$, and three adjacent vertices $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, and $\vec{c}$:
$$\bbox{\vec{o} = \left[\begin{matrix} o_x \\ o_y \\ o_z \end{matrix}\right]} ,\quad
\bbox{\vec{a} = \left[\begin{matrix} a_x \\ a_y \\ a_z \end{matrix}\right]} ,\quad
\bbox{\vec{b} = \left[\begin{matrix} b_x \\ b_y \\ b_z \end{matrix}\right]} ,\quad
\bbox{\vec{c} = \left[\begin{matrix} c_x \\ c_y \\ c_z \end{matrix}\right]}$$
All edges of the cuboid (where two faces meet) match one of the vectors
$$\bbox{\vec{e}_a = \vec{a} - \vec{o}} , \quad
\bbox{\vec{e}_b = \vec{b} - \vec{o}} , \quad
\bbox{\vec{e}_c = \vec{c} - \vec{o}}$$
and the eight vertices of the cuboid are at
$$\begin{array}{rll}
\vec{v}_{000} =& \vec{o}                         & = \vec{o} \\
\vec{v}_{001} =& \vec{o} + \vec{e}_a             & = \vec{a} \\
\vec{v}_{010} =& \vec{o} + \vec{e}_b             & = \vec{b} \\
\vec{v}_{011} =& \vec{o} + \vec{e}_a + \vec{e}_b & = \vec{a} + \vec{b} - \vec{o} \\
\vec{v}_{100} =& \vec{o} + \vec{e}_c             & = \vec{c} \\
\vec{v}_{101} =& \vec{o} + \vec{e}_a + \vec{e}_c & = \vec{a} + \vec{c} - \vec{o} \\
\vec{v}_{110} =& \vec{o} + \vec{e}_b + \vec{e}_c & = \vec{b} + \vec{c} - \vec{o} \\
\vec{v}_{111} =& \vec{o} + \vec{e}_a + \vec{e}_b + \vec{e}_c & = \vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c} - 2 \vec{o} \\
\end{array}$$
The centroid for a cuboid (or a parallelepiped; the three edges do not need to be perpendicular to each other) is the sum of the vertex coordinates, divided by eight. If you sum the above, you'll find out that the centroid is at $\vec{p}$,
$$\bbox{\vec{p} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c} - \vec{o} \right) = \left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{a_x + b_x + c_x - o_x}{2} \\
\frac{a_y + b_y + c_y - o_y}{2} \\
\frac{a_z + b_z + c_z - o_z}{2} \\
\end{matrix}\right]}$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the solution!